# Unable to set status on pull request of a different open source project using Github API v3

Tags: curl, github-api

I have a public repository on github on which there is a random pull request. Using Github API v3 and my personal access token, I am able to set the status using :

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/user/DummyProject/statuses/xxx42a7aaa2aab10875aexxxxxxf675a73c52ac?access_token=xxxxxxxx4d765693ac40a4a51cxxxx7a3100ef50"   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -X POST   -d "{\"state\": \"success\", \"context\":\"BuildBot\", \"description\": \"build success\", \"target_url\": \"http://www.example.com\"}"
```

However, I need to create a separate github account for this build bot, which will set the build statuses on my projects. The moment I replace my token with the buildbot token, I get the following response :

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

The token that I generated for buildbot has all the permissions marked, still why this buildbot is not able to set status? The project is open source.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out later that the non-project-owner need to be added as a collaborator in order to set statuses on the project.